# Does "Black Resonance" increase power of all b. magic if b. magic is equipped by other party members?

Tags: bravely-default

Or does it only boost the character with "Black Resonance"? If someone could let me know how exactly this mechanic works, I'd be thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black Resonance only increases magic damage for Black Magic spells when you have other party members with Black Resonance. So, selecting Black Magic or B/W Magic as a secondary job ability will not increase black magic damage if you only have one character with Black Resonance. Once you have multiple characters equipped with Black Resonance, each character will have their black magic damage increased as follows:

1. 0 allies: 1x multiplier (No effect)
2. 1 ally: 1.1x multiplier
3. 2 allies: 1.15x multiplier
4. 3 allies: 1.2x multiplier

Comment: Thanks! Is there a level where Black Resonance is given as a support ability? Or do I basically have to have multiple black mages in my party to reap the benefits?

Comment: You can unlock the Black Resonance ability for general use when you rank Black Mage up to Job Level 8.